# Taylor series of $\ln(1+(1/x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

With $\ln(1+x)$ having a Taylor series of $x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - (x^4)/4 +\dots$
I was wondering how I would modify it for $\ln(1+(1/x))$.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is it near $0$?

Comment: You can't around 0: the function and its derivatives are not defined in 0. If you want you can make a Taylor expansion around a point $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

From properties of logarithmic function:
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = 
\ln\left(\frac{1 + x}{x}\right) = 
\ln\left(1 + x\right) - \ln\left(x\right) = 
\ln\left(1 + x\right) - \ln\left(1 + (x - 1)\right)
$$

Comment: So it is the standard Taylor series of ln(1+x)  - [(x-1) - ((x-1)^2)/2 + ((x-1)^3)/3 - ...]? Awesome! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the expansion at $x=0$ we need to take $x>0$ and therefore

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = 
\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln\left(1+x\right) = 
\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x-\frac12 x^2+\frac13x^3+\ldots =   
$$